# WPF View - UserControl path instead of UserControl content

Tags: wpf, view

What can be the reasons that I see the UserControl path instead of UserControl content?

I have quite complex code, so I just would like to ask for some hints, where I should look for the problem..

This shows when I debug my app:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you have **ConteControl** which binds to *OrderEntryViewModel* but it is not associated with any view. You need

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:OrderEntryViewModel}">
        <userControls:YourView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```